# I am getting crash on firebase console that did not call through to super.onResume()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I am calling super.onresume in every activity, but still the crash report on firebase console. I have BaseActivity where i am overriding onResume() function and extends every activity from BaseActivity. In some activity i override onResume() function and some i use BaseActivity onResume()

**Fatal Exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity } did not call through to super.onResume()
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3725(ActivityThread.java:3725)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3775(ActivityThread.java:3775)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1734(ActivityThread.java:1734)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 110(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 232(Looper.java:232)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6661(ActivityThread.java:6661)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1106(ZygoteInit.java:1106)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 967(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding> : AppCompatActivity() {

    val BASE_EXTRA_TEXT_FOR_INTENT_INJECTION = "com.hello.world"
    val KEY_INJECTION_EXTRA_STRING = "injection_extra_string"

    var mDataBinding: T? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        try {

            mDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, setLayout())


            if (intent.action != null && intent.action!!.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return
            }
            val isSafe = intent.hasExtra(KEY_INJECTION_EXTRA_STRING)
            if (isSafe) {
                val intentInjectionStr = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_INJECTION_EXTRA_STRING)
                if (intentInjectionStr == null || !intentInjectionStr.equals(BASE_EXTRA_TEXT_FOR_INTENT_INJECTION + RootValues.getInstance().TIME_STAMP_FOR_INTENT_INJECTION)) {
                    finish()
                }
            } else {
                finish()
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        try {
            super.onResume()
            if (intent.action != null && intent.action!!.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return
            }
            if (DeviceUtils.isDeviceRooted()) {
                finish()
            }
        } catch (ignore: Exception) {
        }
    }

    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        try {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
            init(savedInstanceState)
        } catch (ignore: Exception) {
        }
    }

    abstract fun setLayout(): Int

    abstract fun init(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

I want to resolve this crash. This crash is coming sometimes.

Comment: why `catch (ignore: Exception)` ignore the exception ?

Comment: you mean to write super.onresume() out of try catch block?

Comment: no, i mean you should be looking at the exception thrown by looking at what `ex: Exception` is saying

Comment: Does it will solve the crash problem? but i will still remove.

Comment: wont solve your crash but you'll start learning why things are crashing or not doing what they should be.

Comment: i'm not saying you should remove the try catch i'm saying you should be printing the value of the exception so you can see what's wrong

Comment: thanks @a_local_nobody for pointing the issue in code.

Comment: The problem is likely caused by exception inside `super.onResume()`. If it does not reproduce on your device, then logging exception won't help. You should let it crash (moving `super.onResume()` outside try..catch) to know what is the problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce on my device, but didn't get the crash. I tried to call super.onResume() outside the try..catch block, but nothing happens. It is only logging on firebase console on live app.
if i remove the super.onResume, then the app crash and give error super not called exception.